# Gmail Apps Marketplace contextual gadget only HelloWorld extractor works

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm developing a google contextual gadget for Apps Marketplace based on this resource https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets.
I've enabled all the necessary APIs, and after configuring the Apps Marketplace SDK and setting up the contextual gadget extractor to google.com:HelloWorld was able to see the gadget on an email containing "Hello World" in the subject and body.

The problem is that none of the other extractors make the gadget appear. I have tried different combinations of Extractor Urls, params and scopes. The gadget won't appear in the email.

**The content of the test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="MessageID" description="" height="20" author="personal" author_email="..." author_location="local">
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>
    <Require feature="google.contentmatch">
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:MessageIDExtractor
      </Param>
    </Require>
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="html" view="card">
    <![CDATA[
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("messageId test"));
      </script>
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

[extractor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjKIK.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made to work other extractors, try to follow this pattern: [gadget settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ4dQ.png)

Supported values for **Extractor param name**: from_email, to_email, cc_email, bcc_email, date_sent, date_received, subject, body, id, list_id, list_unsubscribe